# Loop for outlier detection in R, panel data

Tags: r, loops, outliers, panel-data

I'm working with a panel data frame that looks something like this:

```
        date    w    x    y    z    Country
1    2009 01    21   43   12    3   AT
2    2009 02    32   54   21   16   AT
3    2009 03    14   32   65   32   AT
4    2009 04    65   33   75   21   AT
:        :      :    :    :    :       :
:        :      :    :    :    :       :
55   2009 01    32   58   53   17   BE
56   2009 02    12   47   43   23   BE
57   2009 03    87   43   21   76   BE
:        :      :    :    :    :       :
85   2009 01    12   46   84   29    CZ
86   2009 02    85   29   90   12    CZ
:        :      :    :    :    :       :
:        :      :    :    :    :       :

for total of 28 countries
```

I would like to run a loop to detect possible outlier regions by evaluating the same plm model for different subsets (excluding one country at a time). The subset creation could look something like that:

```
uniq <- unique(unlist(full_panel$Country))
for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
data_1 <- subset(full_panel, Country!=uniq[i])
}
```

and the model to evaluate:

```
plm(data_1, y~x+lag(x)......,
  model="within", effect="individual")
```

After that I'd like the code to produce a data frame by printing one specific statistic (let's say **adj R-sq)** from the results in order to compare the different subsets later on.

For now, I have only tried to create different parts of the code and, since I'm a beginner, having problems writing the last piece and combining them all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There is an `outliers`-package, but I find that most of the efforts to search for "outliers" are based on such faulty and dangerous statistical thinking that I usually ignore (or say something negative) about such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `by` to run operations across subsets of a dataframe returning a list (equal to number of distinct grouping) containing the return items from function, here being a dataframe of each subsetted data's `plm` model results.

```
model_results_list <- by(full_panel, full_panel$Country, FUN=function(sub_df){

            fit <- plm(sub_df, y~x+lag(x)......,
                       model="within", effect="individual")

            data.frame(country = max(sub_df$Country),
                       f_stat = summary(fit)$fstatistic$statistic,
                       r_sq = summary(fit)$r.squared['rsq'],
                       adj_rsq = summary(fit)$r.squared['adjrsq'],
                       rss = sum(resid(fit)^2)
            )    
})

# BIND ALL DFS TO ONE SINGULAR DF
country_models_df <- do.call(rbind, model_results_list)
```